# "un-committing" a file from a pushed changeset in gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

I have a commit with two files changed (file a and b), I pushed it to gerrit repo (but not yet merged). Now I realize I dont need to update b. How do I push a new changeset that removes/un-commits b and only includes file a?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your your local repository do the following:

1. Remove file-b from the commit

   ```
   git reset HEAD^ -- file-b
   ```
2. Amend the commit without the file-b

   ```
   git commit --amend
   ```
3. Discard file-b changes

   ```
   git checkout -- file-b
   ```
4. Confirm that everything is OK

   ```
   git status
   git log
   git diff HEAD^ HEAD
   ```
5. Push the new commit to Gerrit (new patchset)

   ```
   git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
   ```

Comment: Nice! in step 1, should the two hyphens removed? (just before "file-b" )

Comment: No, the two hyphens are really required.

Answer (score -1):

Since I am not allowed to comment I have to warn other users that following
Marcelo Ávila de Oliveira's solution does not work as of Nov 14 2022. Instead of keeping the commit SHA a new commit is performed, which in turn triggers my
gerrit commit-msg hook to issue a new Change-Id, thereby destroying the current working copy of the patchset to modify

Comment: Are referring to step 2 (git commit --amend)? Yes, it generates a new commit (every time you change an existing commit, actually, a new commit is created) but this will NOT change the commit Change-Id.